# All my MPI programs (written in c) give a segmentation fault

Tags: c, mpi

I have written some basic programs in C using MPI. Some of them used to work untill yesterday. Today I get segmentation faults from most of them. One goes an infinite loop, but I've no loops in it. This is really making me mad.
This is the program that goes on loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, nprocs, maxn, i, j, local_counter, global_counter;

    MPI_Status status;  
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm comm;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);  /* Number of processes */  
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int N = 0; /*Number of prime numbers I've found*/

    if (rank == 0){
        printf("What is the maximum number to check?");
        scanf("%d", &maxn); 
     }

     MPI_Finalize();
     return 0;    
}
```

Comment: "used to work" is a tricky thing. What has changed? An update to your system / libraries? something else?

Comment: What's your compilation command? Any warnings? Do you have all warnings on?

Comment: I haven't changed anything i these programs, but i've workes in other programs in MPI.

Comment: I've compiled using mpicc and mpirun

Comment: I've also tried programs taken from internet and they don't work. I get [Zen:02669] *** Process received signal ***
[Zen:02669] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[Zen:02669] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[Zen:02669] Failing at address: (nil)

Comment: [Zen:02669] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f237ed03390]
[Zen:02669] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__isoc99_fscanf+0x5d)[0x7f237e99384d]
[Zen:02669] [ 2] Matrix-Vector-Multi_MPI.exe[0x40125c]
[Zen:02669] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f237e948830]
[Zen:02669] [ 4] Matrix-Vector-Multi_MPI.exe[0x400c39]
[Zen:02669] *** End of error message ***
-----------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 2669 on node Zen exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).

Comment: Please show the actual compilation command.

Comment: Please [edit] all the extra info into your question.

Comment: Add logging so you can see which lines of code it's successfully executing and which one is not returning.

Comment: I've just tried a program taken from the web using this command:  mpicc Matrix-Vector-Multi_MPI.c  -o Matrix-Vector-Multi_MPI.exe     and then  mpirun -np 2 Matrix-Vector-Multi_MPI.exe

Comment: There are quite a few hits when I search for "mpirun noticed that process rank 0 exited on signal 11" (leaving out the PID and Zen part). Have you looked at and tried any of those questions & solutions (both here on SO and elsewhere)?

Comment: And that program worked yesterday, and not today?

Comment: Also, is your `mpi.h` local (in the same source directory), but your library file not? Are you sure they are compatible, and that the library is properly found?

Comment: I've tried to fix it all the afternoon, but I didn't get to solve the problem.

Comment: mpi.h is not local

Comment: Programs that do not use MPI work properly. Maybe something changed in status?

Comment: Aside: "It worked yesterday". Please try to develop a working style that allows you to revert. Without a formal tool, a simple approach is that every time you reach a successful stage, make a folder and copy every file there, with version notes. Even with micro changes, drag each file to a "copy-of" before you edit it, so you can easily revert.

Comment: you're using stdin in MPI.. `scanf("%d", &maxn); ` - I don't think that will work. Read it as a command line argument or from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf` you are trying to read from `stdin` which is generally not admissible in MPI and on my system (a computer cluster) it causes the program to stall and run "infinitely".

What you need to do is either read your value from a file or as a command line argument.

Here is the command line argument version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, nprocs, maxn, i, j, local_counter, global_counter;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm comm;
    /* Number of processes */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);  
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    /* Number of prime numbers I've found */
    int N = 0; 

   // Usage check
   if(argc!=2){
        printf("Error\n");
        printf("Syntax mpi_in <Maximum number to check>\n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    maxn = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (rank == 0){
        printf("Maximum number to check is: %d \n", maxn);
     }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

In the command line argument version you may as well make all the processes unpack the argument, here for a demonstration process 0 prints the value.

Calling `MPI_Init` cleans the argument list so after that the program uses `argc` and `argv[]` as if it is a non-MPI program. This is apparently not a guaranteed behavior, but it works on two different systems I'm using. In this case `argc` will be 2 since the first argument is always the name of the program. You can run it from the terminal as, for instance with 5 processes,

```
mpirun -np 5 mpi_in 300
```

Note that since `argv` is an array of pointers to strings, the program needs `atoi` to convert the number from string to int.

Comment: I've tried on a program and I think you're right. Tomorrow I'm going to think better about it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Good to hear, it definitely worked for me. Let me know if you're interested in the file solution. There seem to be ways to include stdin in MPI but if you think about submitting a job to a queue that just doesn't seem right!