# Sum from arguments MPI with c

Tags: c, mpi

I have to implement sum reduction, which calculates sum from 0 to a specific number from arguments. I use the following to get the sum from a variable , but i don't know how to use arguments and calculate the sum with processes with my master process. How can i make this using arguments. I use [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/) Library.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  ARRAYSIZE  16
#define  MASTER     0

float  data[ARRAYSIZE];

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int   numtasks, taskid, rc, dest, offset, i, j, tag1, tag2, source, chunksize; 
    float mysum, sum;
    float update(int myoffset, int chunk, int myid);
    MPI_Status status;

    /***** Initializations *****/
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    if (numtasks % 4 != 0) {
       printf("Quitting. Number of MPI tasks must be divisible by 4.\n");
       MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
       exit(0);
    }
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
    printf ("MPI task %d has started...\n", taskid);
    chunksize = (ARRAYSIZE / numtasks);
    tag2 = 1;
    tag1 = 2;

    /***** Master task only ******/
    if (taskid == MASTER){

        /* Initialize the array */
        sum = 0;
        for(i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
            data[i] =  i * 1.0;
            sum = sum + data[i];
        }
        printf("Initialized array sum = %e\n",sum);

        /* Send each task its portion of the array - master keeps 1st part */
        offset = chunksize;
        for (dest=1; dest<numtasks; dest++) {
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&data[offset], chunksize, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("Sent %d elements to task %d offset= %d\n",chunksize,dest,offset);
            offset = offset + chunksize;
        }

        /* Master does its part of the work */
        offset = 0;
        mysum = update(offset, chunksize, taskid);

        /* Wait to receive results from each task */
        for (i=1; i<numtasks; i++) {
            source = i;
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&data[offset], chunksize, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag2,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }

        /* Get final sum and print sample results */  
        MPI_Reduce(&mysum, &sum, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Sample results: \n");
        offset = 0;
        for (i=0; i<numtasks; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<5; j++) 
                printf("  %e",data[offset+j]);
            printf("\n");
           offset = offset + chunksize;
        }
        printf("*** Final sum= %e ***\n",sum);

   }  /* end of master section */



   /***** Non-master tasks only *****/

   if (taskid > MASTER) {

      /* Receive my portion of array from the master task */
      source = MASTER;
      MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&data[offset], chunksize, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag2, 
      MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      mysum = update(offset, chunksize, taskid);

      /* Send my results back to the master task */
      dest = MASTER;
      MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&data[offset], chunksize, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      MPI_Reduce(&mysum, &sum, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  } /* end of non-master */


  MPI_Finalize();

}   /* end of main */


float update(int myoffset, int chunk, int myid) {
    int i; 
    float mysum;
    /* Perform addition to each of my array elements and keep my sum */
    mysum = 0;
    for(i=myoffset; i < myoffset + chunk; i++) {
        data[i] = data[i] + i * 1.0;
        mysum = mysum + data[i];
    }
    printf("Task %d mysum = %e\n",myid,mysum);
    return(mysum);
}
```

For example like this: `$ mpicc -np <# of threads> a.out <number to calculate>`

Comment: What do you mean by arguments? Command line?

Comment: yes, given the specific number from commandline

Comment: $ mpicc -np <# of threads> a.out <number to calculate>

Comment: In that case it's simple. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758925/all-my-mpi-programs-written-in-c-give-a-segmentation-fault/46760107#46760107) is my post related to the same issue. I bet there's more, likely there are not named properly so they're hard to find. Let me know if you have any trouble with it.

Comment: Multiple arguments are straightforward and the few main points are explained in the post. It was all tested and worked on an hpc cluster. I'd post you an exact answer but this is too similar and almost exact.